# want to set alert when page url changes

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0, html

How do I call an event while user trying to leave the page either by navigating to another page or by changing url?
I have tried following methods but its not working.

```
 protected void Page_Unload(object sender, EventArgs e){}

 protected override void OnUnload(EventArgs e){}
```

Thanks,

Comment: you should use javascript for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the bind attribute in jquery.  There may be a point as well where you want to ignore the warning, to do that just create a variable and set it whenever you want the warning to be ignored.

Include the [JQuery library](http://jquery.com/)

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

After that you can add the following javascript to your page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ignore = false;

$(function () {
    $(window).bind('beforeunload', function () {
        if (!ignore) {
            return 'WARNING: Data you have entered may not be saved.';
        }
    });

    $('.ignorepostback').live('click',function () {
        ignore = true;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I am getting following error while executing above code-"Microsoft JScript runtime error: The value of the property '$' is null or undefined, not a Function object"

Comment: You need to add the Jquery library, I edited the post to reflect that.

Comment: If you add a link to your page with the css class ignorepostback it will fire that function.  So if you have a link where when someone clicks it you just want to ignore and let them go just add the class ignorepostback.  <a href="..." class="ignorepostback">Click Here</a>

Answer (score 1):

You cann't do that server side.

You could try to implement something clientside for example by hooking up the unload event of the window. Or by using the [unload handler](http://api.jquery.com/unload/) in jquery

```
$(window).unload(function() {
  alert('Do not bug users with alerts or try to keep them on your site');
});
```

Keep in mind that users in general don't like webistes that bug them when they decided to leave...

Answer (score 1):

by javascript , you can do it using `onbeforeunload`

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  return 'Dialog text here.';
};
```

Comment: This is the more correct (as it were) method of checking a user really does want to leave the page. It implements a feature built into the browser (see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onbeforeunload). I would imagine this option is less likely to be blocked by ad block software.